# Maximization inequality for Frobenius norm after adding orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, optimization, normed-spaces

Let $A$ be a matrix and $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix such that $AQ^T$ is symmetric, positive semidefinite. Show that $$||A+Q||_F\geq||A+P||_F$$ for any orthogonal matrix $P$. Here, $||\cdot||_F$ is the Frobenius norm.

Comment: This is equivalent to solving the [orthogonal procrustes problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $AQ^T=VDV^T$ be an orthogonal diagonalisation. Then $D$ is a nonnegative diagonal matrix and $U=V^TPQ^TV$ is orthogonal. Since Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant, we have
\begin{aligned}
\|A+Q\|_F^2-\|A+P\|_F^2
&=\|V^T(A+Q)Q^TV\|_F^2-\|V^T(A+P)Q^TV\|_F^2\\
&=\|D+I\|_F^2-\|D+U\|_F^2\\
&=2\operatorname{tr}(D)-\operatorname{tr}(DU)-\operatorname{tr}(U^TD)\\
&=2\operatorname{tr}(D(I-U)),
\end{aligned}
but this trace is nonnegative because $D(I-U)$ has a nonnegative diagonal.